# Reactjs sending updated state info in to all its child components

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-proptypes

React parent component:

```
return(
<div className="child">
 {this.state.showChild2} ? <Child2> : <Child1 />
</div>
<div className="child">
 {this.state.showChildA} ? <Child2> : <Child1 />
</div>
<div className="child">
 {this.state.showChildB} ? <Child2> : <Child1 />
</div>
<div className="child">
 {this.state.showChildC} ? <Child2> : <Child1 />
</div>

in parents state I have a flag for 
this.state = {
 activeBTN = "red"
}
```

and this keeps toggling between red and blue - for example -
how do I pass this to all child components when it is changed all child components must re-render - call different action creators.

Comment: Add an attribute for `<Child1 />` and `<Child2 />`? For instance, `<Child1 active={this.state.showChild2} />`. (I am not sure this is what you are really asking.) Note that I assume `this.state.showChild2` is a boolean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1793682/andre-leethanks for your help, yes it does send the initial state to child - but when the status is changed in parent, I am seeing an error: <br> bundle.js:10623 Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`  <br />

Comment: It will be helpful if you can write a minimize sample on CodePen. When the warning you met happen, sometimes you pass the value to an input type's `value`.

Comment: <div className="child">
 {this.state.showChildC} ? <Child2 active=[this.state.btncolor}> : <Child1 />
</div> I am seeing the value and when I click the changebtn on parent - I am able to see the updated value in Child's componentWillReceiveProps() nextProps.value - but I am seeing the above error in parent's component -

Comment: when I did some research - it will go away if I add a default value? but where should I add that? In place of active? i didnot quite get that - sorry my code is bit complex - cant post it on codepen..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe it clearly. The term I used "input type's value" should be "form related's value" such as `input`, etc. If you are using a form member, you need to know something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645377/how-to-include-a-text-input-in-a-react-component-with-its-value-specified).