# How to include a text input in a React component with its value specified?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I need to include a text input in a React component, with its initial value passed from the component's props:

```
 <input value={this.props.value} type='text'/>
```

But the input is not editable, and React complains:

```
 Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field.
```

So I add a onChange event handler:

```
 <input value={this.props.value} type='text' onChange={this.valueChanged} />
```

What should I do in the valueChanged handler to update the input value? Do I have to use state?

Comment: Yes you would have to use state...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation on forms, specifically [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Your `valueChanged()` method, where the change event is handled, would do something like this:

```
valueChanged(event) {
  this.setState({
    value: event.target.value //set this.state.value to the input's value
  });
}
```

That means that yes, your input value would need to use state  (`this.state.value`.) If you want `this.state.value` to be populated from `this.props.value`, you could do something like this in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value: props.value //passed prop as initial value
  }
  this.valueChanged = this.valueChanged.bind(this);
}
```

The above will initially set `this.state.value` to the passed prop `value`'s value. Then apply the value from state and the `onChange` handler to your `<input>`:

```
<input value={this.state.value} type="text" onChange={this.valueChanged} />
```

Since `this.state.value` is the current input value, and is updated every time that value is changed, it becomes input-able as expected.

Here's a fiddle (thanks, Andrew): http://jsfiddle.net/ow99x7d5/2

Comment: Since you beat me ;), if you needed a live demo, here's something I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/ow99x7d5/

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks for the edits. I modified the code to remove the `(event) => this.valueChanged(event)` since it can be resolved simply by binding `this.valueChanged` in the constructor. Feels a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I was wondering if there is a way without using state, like using setProps(deprecated).

Comment: @ZackTanner Sure, no problem :-).

Comment: @NeoWang Is there a reason why state shouldn't be used?

Comment: @AndrewLi No, I was just starting to learn react, exploring all the possibilities.

Comment: @NeoWang This would be the "react way" of doing it. I'd say any other way is a hack or ill-advised. Have a look at Thinking in React: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html